# libraries to read compiler flags from a CMake build tree

Tags: cmake

[YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) is an awesome vim plugin for C++, however, it requires a user provided `.ycm_extra_conf.py` script to return compiler flags for each C/C++ source.

Currently I have a CMake based C++ project, and I want to use this plugin to ease my development, then I need to write the `.ycm_extra_conf.py` script to *programmatically* figure out the compiler flag for each source file.

So my question is, is there a way to *programatically* find out the compiler flags for each source by looking into the build directory, given I have ran cmake and generated a bunch of files.

Answer (score 0):

There won't be a generic solution as CMake can generate build solution for different platforms and programs, e.g. Makefiles vs. Visual Studio projects.

For the Makefile generator you could try to find the relevant information in the CMakeFiles/CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake files or directly from the Makefiles. But this is probably not a very reliable solution because these files are internals of the Makefile generator and might change with every CMake version.

The solution that Eclipse uses is to parse the output of the compiler invocations for include flags etc. This is probably a bit more reliable. For Makefiles you can enable full output by compiling with VERBOSE=1 given as environment or call variable to make.